# How tall is Heimdall in the movie 'Thor'?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-2011

The actor who plays Heimdall, Idris Elba, stands 6'3" and Tom Hiddleston, the actor who plays Loki, is 6'2". Though these actors are very close to the same height, when Loki approaches Heimdall on Bifrost bridge, just before freezing him and letting Laufey and a couple other Frost Giants into Asgard, Heimdall appears to be at least a foot taller than Loki. I assume Loki is being presented as a normal 6'2" tall Asgardian, whereas Heimdall is being presented as about 8' tall. How tall is he suppose to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/Heimdall_%28Earth-616%29), the Heimdall seen in the 616 universe is **7' 2" tall.**

There seems to be no special reason to assume that the [Heimdall](http://marvel.wikia.com/Heimdall_%28Earth-199999%29) seen in the Earth-19999 (movie) universe is any different.

[image]

Comment: You're awesome! I tried for about an hour to find that still. In it we can see that Heimdall is taking a long stride, crouched and leaning forward to deliver a sword stroke and even there we can see he's a foot taller that Loki who is standing with good posture. If Heimdall stood up straight, he appears to be a solid 8' tall. I think I need to revise the OP.

Comment: Comicvine describes Loki as being 6'4'' http://www.comicvine.com/loki/4005-4324/